# what is the CSS to create this font?

Tags: css

i'm not a css expert, but i'm trying to copy some of the fonts from this link:

[developers.slidedeck.com](http://developers.slidedeck.com/)

if you scroll down to the section with the heading "What do you get?".  the only relevant style i see for this H3 title is:

```
font-size: 45px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-bottom: 20px;
color: 
#E4E4E4;
letter-spacing: -0.02em;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
```

i've copied that css into my site and my fonts don't look quite exactly like theirs.  and from what i can see, they are not using any special font generator plugins (like cufon).

so how is it my fonts can't look like theirs exactly if it's pure CSS?  and to explain the differences - my fonts aren't as skinny and my G doesn't look like theirs.

Comment: Why not copy the entire HTML+CSS for that page, and edit it down as far as you can.  Does it still look the same?

Comment: There are different approaches to include a font into a web page (not only cufon). Check http://www.solidstategroup.com/what-we-think/a-comparison-between-sifr-cufon-and-font-face

Comment: It might work just by adding this line : `<link rel='stylesheet' id='slidedeck_theme_fonts-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro%3A400%2C900%7COswald&#038;ver=0.4.2' type='text/css' media='all' />`

Comment: ssx that's an iteresting solution :) it did indeed work, but do i really want to rely on THEIR css for my styles? :  thanks for the answers, i think i will just download their entire css and steal what i need :)

Comment: oh wow, i just stuck that url in the browser and all the font-face definitions are there!  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using @font-face to include this font.

I think they are using the font google api https://developers.google.com/webfonts/

Comment: The exact line is: <link id="slidedeck_theme_fonts-css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro%3A400%2C900%7COswald&ver=0.4.2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>

Comment: ah yes i got it now, just stuck that in the url and can use all their font faces. :)  thx

Answer (score 1):

The font they are using is Oswald which is available from Google Web Fonts and it gives you instructions on how to import it to your website.

http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Oswald